# unnest list in pyspark

Tags: list, pyspark, unnest

I am trying to use `combineByKey` to find the median per key for my assignment (using `combineByKey` is a requirement of the assignment) and I'm planning to use the following function to return `(k, v)` pairs where `v = a` list of all values associated with the same key. After that, I plan to sort the values and then find the median.

```
data = sc.parallelize([('A',2), ('A',4), ('A',9), ('A',3), ('B',10), ('B',20)])

rdd = data.combineByKey(lambda value: value, lambda c, v: median1(c,v), lambda c1, c2: median2(c1,c2))

def median1 (c,v):
    list = [c]
    list.append(v)
    return list

def median2 (c1,c2):
    list2 = [c1]
    list2.append(c2)
    return list2
```

However, my code gives output like this:

> [('A', [[2, [4, 9]], 3]), ('B', [10, 20])]

where value is a nested list. Is there anyway that I can unnest the values in pyspark to get

> [('A', [2, 4, 9, 3]), ('B', [10, 20])]

Or is there other ways I can find the median per key using `combineByKey`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't make a good combiner out of the value.

Here is your answer :

```
data = sc.parallelize([('A',2), ('A',4), ('A',9), ('A',3), ('B',10), ('B',20)])

def createCombiner(value):
    return [value]
def mergeValue(c, value):
    return c.append(value)
def mergeCombiners(c1, c2):
    return c1+c2

rdd = data.combineByKey(createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners)
```

> [('A', [9, 4, 2, 3]), ('B', [10, 20])]

Comment: Thanks! I tried but I got [('A', [9, 4, 2, 3]), ('B', None)] and I guess it has something to do with how spark randomly partitioned the data. I tried to update the function to the below but it still doesnt solve the problem. Do you have any idea to solve it? Thank you.

def createCombiner(value):
    return [value]
def mergeValue(c, value):
 if c == []:
  result = value
 elif value == []:
  result = c
 else: 
  result = c.append(value)
 return result
def mergeCombiners(c1, c2):
 if c1 == []:
  result = c2
 elif c2 == []:
  result = c1
 else: 
  result = c1+c2
 return result

Comment: I don't know, it worked for me. Regarding the update you tried to make : each function should return an array, where c is an array and v is an integer here. So at least it would be "if c==[]: return [value]"

Answer (score 0):

it's way easier to use `collect_list` on a dataframe column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

df = rdd.toDF(['key', 'values'])

key_lists = df.groupBy('key').agg(collect_list('values').alias('value_list'))
```